# Need Help in sql query to get substring from string value

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have string value as "ORA_Sampl_34_20120530_123456.txt"
from this string i want to get output as "34" using sql query.

Comment: Did you even try? `SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX` **[Extracting numbers with SQL Server](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/extracting-numbers-with-sql-server/)**

Comment: every time it wont be number, it can string value also

Comment: But the mechanism how to detect start/end and substring are the same. The point is you want to someone else do your job.

Comment: The format would be standard right?

Comment: here i want value after 2nd Underscore and before 3rd Underscore

Comment: @Ullas, yes this format would be standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution should be good for learning:

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(50) = 'ORA_Sampl_34_20120530_123456.txt',
        @start INT,
        @end INT

SELECT @start = CHARINDEX('_', @text, CHARINDEX('_',@text,1)+1)+1
SELECT @end = CHARINDEX('_',@text, @start)

SELECT SUBSTRING(@text, @start, @end - @start)
```

Comment: thanks @rafal for soultion

Comment: I'm glad it help you.